# Not in executable format: File format not recognized GDB

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdb

I'm tried to debug my binary file (called click) with gdb.

When I run

```
gdb ./click
```

I have the following error

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.10-1ubuntu2) 7.10
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
"/home/student/Desktop/./click": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

The outupt of:

```
uname -a
```

is

```
Linux student 4.2.0-36-lowlatency #42-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu May 12 23:39:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And if I run

```
file click
```

I get this output:

```
click: ERROR: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 error reading (Invalid argument)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share the command you are using to compile your program?

Comment: I compile the program with eclipse and I tried to run the binary file in another computer.

Comment: What does `uname -a` output on the computer where you compile the program?

Comment: On the computer where gdb gives you that error, what happens if, outside of gdb, you try to run `./click` ?

Comment: @CristiFati the output of `uname -a` in the computer where I compile the program is:  `Linux elisabetta-XPS-13-9343 4.2.0-36-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:05:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick when I try to run ./click outside gdb it gives me a segmentation fault (core dump).

Answer (score 5):

> `click: ERROR: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 error reading (Invalid argument)`

Your file is simply corrupt.

Possibly it is truncated (did you run out of disk space when linking it?), or you transferred it over FTP from another machine in ASCII mode (use binary mode instead).

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I transferred a new file and it works!

Comment: I have the same problem. I compile my program on my host and tftp it to my target .